Brother HL-L3270CDW prints always in color
Ubuntu 24.04.1. After turning the printer on, two printers show:
Brother_HL_L3270CDW _series and Brother_HL_L3270CDW_series_USB. The first one does nothing, the second one always prints in color, no matter whether the "Monochrome" setting is there or not.
